# OpenGL not using GLUT , and has its own GUI can i use GLUT without problem?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have application that using only gl/glu on windows using wglCreateContext context.
the application has its own keys managers , now i like to implement GUI framework for input box and select lists.
i found [anttweakbar](http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools%3aanttweakbar) for example that have to use GLUT. can i avoid using GLUT
but still have some kind of input text's in my app?

Answer (score 2):

anttweakbar doesn't depend on GLUT. You can use it with whatever toolkit you like.

Comment: in the examples its only glut,GLFW,SDL,SMFL,DX , no win32 open gl

Comment: So? You've given the building blocks. Init with TwInit(TW_OPENGL, NULL); and pump the messages with TwEventWin(wnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

Comment: there are some really good and easy examples on their website, where integration with GLUT is shown: http://anttweakbar.sourceforge.net/doc/tools:anttweakbar:examples#twsimpleglut